# Visual Studio auto generated code from gRPC .proto file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-c#

I'm facing an issue where it seems that Visual Studio is changing the way objects look in a .proto file.

.proto file: [concordium_p2p_rpc.proto](http://.proto%20file:%20https://github.com/Concordium/concordium-grpc-api)

Example - this is in the .proto file:

```
message BlockHash {
  string block_hash = 1;
}
```

After building my project I want to create an instance of this exact object, however, the property inside the object is now called "BlockHash_" and not "block_hash" as in the .proto file.

The confusion is complete if I try to serialize this object to JSON... Then the attribute is now called "blochHash"... a 3rd name.

So in .proto

```
{
    "block_hash": ""
}
```

becomes in C#

```
BlockHash bh = new BlockHash()
{
    BlockHash_: ""
}
```

and then when serialized

```
{
    "blockHash": ""
}
```

What is with that?

Comment: Make sure you do a clean build.  The intermediate obj files may not of gotten updated.  You are probably using a different version of Net and may want to change the default target version of net in the project.

Comment: I have tried both Core 3.1 and .NET 5, if this is what you mean? I have tried to "clean" and then "build" it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I found the answer to this question myself in this article.

https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2020/01/06/defining-grpc-messages.aspx

Why Microsoft decides to perform this renaming instead of just keeping the names are as they are in the .proto file, is beyond me and evidently it introduces problems that I don't see would have been there otherwise.

What happens is that Visual Studio wants to be the boss of what things are called, and therefore it wants to rename the attribute "block_hash" of the object **BlockHash** by making the first letter upper case, removing the underscore and making the first letter of the next word an upper case as well => "BlockHash".

However, since this is the name of the class itself, this name is probably problematic since class constructors use this name and therefore Visual Studio fixes it's own dodo be adding a tailing underscore, resulting in an attribute named "BlockHash_".

Why oh why do you do these things?!....